# Gremlin how to get nodes that do NOT point to nodes with certain id?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

[image]

Lets say in modern graph starting from person 1. How would we find the following:

```
  All nodes that person 1 knows. That have NOT created a software by id 5.
  Result would be person 2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All nodes that person 1 knows. That have NOT created a software by id 5.
>     Result would be person 2.

```
gremlin> g.V(1).out('knows').not(out('created').hasId(5))
==>v[2]
```